# Strange behavior of dynamic cast and static cast

Tags: c++, oop, casting, virtual-functions, dynamic-cast

This program runs without any exception. Can you please explain why the dynamic cast and static casts are successful? And how C++ manages to resolve the required virtual function?

```
class Shape 
    {
    private :
        string helperFunction();

    public : 
        virtual void draw() = 0;
        virtual void type();
    };

void Shape::type()
    {
    cout << "Shape Type";
    }

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

class Circle : public Shape
    {
    private: 
    string circlething;

    public :
        virtual void draw();
        virtual void type();
        void CircleFunction();
    };

void Circle::draw()
    {
    cout <<"Circle Draw" << endl;
    }

void Circle::type()
    {
    cout <<"Circle Type" << endl;
    }

void Circle::CircleFunction()
    {
    circlething = "Circle Thing";
    cout << circlething;
    cout << "Circle Function" << endl;
    }


class Square : public Shape
    {
    private :
        string  squarething;
    public :
        virtual void draw();
        virtual void type();
        void SquareFunction();
    };

void Square::draw()
    {
    cout <<"Square Draw" << endl;
    }

void Square::type()
    {
    cout <<"Square Type" << endl;
    }

void Square::SquareFunction()
    {
    squarething = "Square Thing";
    cout << squarething;
    cout << "Square Function" << endl;
    }
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
    {
    vector<Shape *> shapes;
    Circle circle;
    Square square;
    shapes.push_back(&circle);
    shapes.push_back(&square);

    vector<Shape *>::const_iterator i;

    for (i = shapes.begin(); i < shapes.end(); ++i)
        {

        cout << "\n*** Simple Type ***\n" << endl;
        (*i)->type();
        (*i)->draw();

        cout << "---Static Cast Circle--" << endl;
        Circle* circle = static_cast<Circle*>(*i);
        circle->type();
        circle->draw();
        circle->CircleFunction();

        cout << "---Static Cast Square--" << endl;
        Square* square = static_cast<Square*>(*i);
        square->type();
        square->draw();
        square->SquareFunction();

        cout << "---Static Cast Circle to Shape --" << endl;
        Shape* shape1 = static_cast<Shape*> (circle);
        shape1->type();
        shape1->draw();

        cout << "--- Dynamic Cast Circle to Shape --" << endl;
        Shape* shape2 = dynamic_cast<Shape*> (circle);
        shape2->type();
        shape2->draw();

        cout << "--- Static Cast Square to Shape --" << endl;
        Shape* shape3 = static_cast<Shape*> (square);
        shape3->type();
        shape3->draw();

        cout << "--- Dynamic Cast Square to Shape --" << endl;
        Shape* shape4 = dynamic_cast<Shape*> (square);
        shape4->type();
        shape4->draw();

        }
    int x;
    cin >> x;
    return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's start with why it isn't throwing any exceptions, since it's pretty simple: `dynamic_cast` throws an exception when you try to cast a *reference* type, and it fails. When you use `dynamic_cast` on pointers, it will return a pointer if it succeeds, or a null pointer if it fails.

As for why you've never getting a failed cast, all your `dynamic_cast` are *up* the hierarchy, to produce a `Shape *`. Since all the objects in question *are* derived from `Shape`, this will always succeed -- and in fact, that conversion can be done implicitly.

To demonstrate what `dynamic_cast` is really intended to do, let's write some slightly different code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Shape {
public : 
    virtual void draw() = 0;
};

class Circle : public Shape
{
public :
    virtual void draw() { cout << "Circle Draw\n"; }
    void circlefunc() { cout << "circle func\n"; }
};

class Square : public Shape
{
public :
    virtual void draw() { cout << "Square Draw\n"; }
    void squarefunc() { cout << "Square Func\n"; }
};

int main() {
    vector<Shape *> shapes;
    Circle circle;
    Square square;
    shapes.push_back(&circle); // implicit conversion from Circle * to Shape *
    shapes.push_back(&square); // implicit conversion from Square * to Shape *

    Circle *c;
    Square *s;
    for (int i=0; i<shapes.size(); i++) {
        shapes[i]->draw(); // draw polymorphically
        if (c = dynamic_cast<Circle *>(shapes[i])) // try to cast to Circle *
            c->circlefunc();               // if it worked, invoke circlefunc
        else if (s = dynamic_cast<Square *>(shapes[i])) // likewise for square
            s->squarefunc();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This time we're using the dynamic_cast to get from `Shape *` to `Square *` or `Circle *`. This will succeed if and only if the dynamic type of the pointee object is that type. Otherwise it'll produce a null pointer. If and only if we get a non-null pointer, we invoke the member function for that specific type.

To summarize: When you have a pointer/reference to a derived object, you can convert to a pointer/reference to the base class implicitly. You don't need `dynamic_cast` (or any explicit cast at all) because this is always safe.

When you convert from pointer/reference to base to get a pointer/reference to derived, *then* you normally want to use a `dynamic_cast`. This will succeed/fail based on whether the actual type of the pointee object (i.e., the dynamic type) is the desired target (or a base of it) or not. In this case, failure is signaled differently depending on whether you're working with pointers or references. For a reference, failure will throw an exception. For a pointer, failure will produce a null pointer.

Comment: Can you explain why the static casts are also successful?

Comment: @kunj2aan: `static_cast` doesn't even attempt to figure out whether the conversion you're attempting is valid. In your case, it probably appears to work primarily because your member functions don't use any class data, so invoking them with a `this` pointer that points to the wrong data doesn't cause visible harm/problems.

Comment: Hi. I modified the code with new member functions and the program still pases without any problem. Is that what you meant?

Answer (score 3):

Why should it? `dynamic_cast` returns `NULL` if the cast failed, it doesn't throw an exception for pointers.

Also, that aside, why should it fail? Both `Square` and `Circle` are `Shape`s. So the cast is fine.

The output is as you see it because of basic polymorphism. You have a `Shape*` that points to a `Square` object, or to a `Circle` object. The `virutal` function calls call the overriden method from the most derived class. This is a **central** aspect of OOP.

On most implementations, this is achieved through `virtual function tables`. Although you have a `Shape*`, the object holds a pointer to a virtual function table inside. Because that member doesn't change during the cast, it points to the virtual function table of a `Square` or a `Circle`, so the calls are resolved correctly.

[image]

Comment: Just as a note, the OP inserting a `Circle*` and a `Square* ` into the `vector<Shape*>`, and then as it iterates is casting the to both a `Square*` and a `Circle*`.  So OP is casting the Circle into a Square (via the shared Shape base)

Answer (score 1):

You are using `dynamic_cast` convert from a derived type to a base type and there is no ambiguity.  Why did you expect that to fail?  Also, using `dynamic_cast` on pointers will not throw an exception (instead it will return `NULL`).  It can throw an exception when casting between type references.

Your `static_cast` is successful because of the way your simple classes are constructed.  Since the `CircleFunction()` and `SquareFunction()` don't actually attempt to access any invalid class member variables, then the program is able to run successfully (luckily), converting incorrectly between types using `static_cast` is not something you should be doing.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer:  When you're doing the `static_cast<Square>` on the Circle pointer and `static_cast<Circle>` on the Square pointer, you've wandered into Undefined Behavior.  Nearly anything could happen at that point.

Also, when you call `dynamic_cast`, it could fail and return NULL if you're casting to a pointer.  It only throws exceptions if you're converting to a reference.  Also, the compiler can choose to replace the dynamic_cast with a compile time cast if it knows at compile time that there is no ambiguity (which is the case here, since you're casting from child->parent).

The output you're getting is because the classes are similar enough to one another that while the casts aren't legal, they managed to work anyway.  Given the undefined behavior, it's impossible to rely on that if you continue making changes.